# Inquiry about energest and low-power modes in Contiki-NG Cooja

Tags: cooja, contiki-ng

I am currently working with Contiki-NG and experimenting with energest and simple-energest in Cooja for power consumption analysis. However, I have encountered an issue where the Low Power Mode (LPM) always shows 0 when using these tools in Cooja.

I would like to inquire if there is a specific procedure or code snippet to enable LPM mode in Cooja for accurate power consumption simulation. Are there any settings or configurations that I might be missing?

Additionally, I am curious whether testing in a real-world environment is necessary to observe LPM transitions accurately, or if there are ways to simulate low-power scenarios within the Cooja environment.

Any guidance, suggestions, or insights on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance.